# Permission denied while trying to connect to local Postgres database using systemd

Tags: postgresql, go, systemd, systemctl

I have a Go program which connects to PostgreSQL database:

```
psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)
```

I build it and it works well, if I run it normally in terminal like this:

```
/./my_program
```

I also have system service:

```
[Unit]
Description=My program

[Service]
ExecStart=/./my_program

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And if I try to use this service, I get:

```
dial tcp [::1]:5432: connect: permission denied
```

I don't know why running this program in terminal normally doesn't cause a problem, but running it as a system service causes a problem.

Comment: Is there a corresponding message in the PostgreSQL server's log file?

Comment: Try again with SELinux disabled.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe disabling SELinux helped, thanks